# JavaScript encrypt string without key?

Tags: javascript, string, encryption

I want to encrypt a string in JavaScript without a key to decrpyt so if people find the encrypted string they cannot decrypt

Comment: What have you already found to solve this problem ? Have you already heard about symmetric-keys and asymmetric-keys encryption ? And mostly, what's the point of having an encrypted string that cannot be decrypted ?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a hash? Hard to tell, the question is too vague. It's not even a question actually.

Comment: I want to encrypt a textbox then verify the encrypted string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple MD5 encryption: [md5.js](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/jshash-2.2.zip)

`$(document).ready(function() {
     document.write(hex_md5('foo'));
 });`

Comment: how do I call the function on the page on want to execute on?

Comment: @Derek Include jQuery.

Comment: @Jay just call the `hex_md5(yourString);`

Comment: Does that `document.write` call not overwrite the whole page?